# How to set the caret position on an editable iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, contenteditable, caret

I need to set the caret position on a contentEditable iframe. It needs to work on Google Chrome and Firefox (no need for IE).

How can I do that?

I've tried

```
var ifr = document.querySelector(".myIframe");
var idoc = ifr.contentDocument;
var ibody = ifr.contentDocument.body; // content: "teststring|"

var caret = 2;

var sel = ifr.contentDocument.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

var el = ibody;
range.setStart(el, caret);
range.setEnd(el, caret);
```

And nothing happens on Chrome... What do I have to change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This *should* work:

```
var ifr = document.querySelector(".myIframe");
var idoc = ifr.contentDocument;
var ibody = ifr.contentDocument.body; // content: "teststring|"

var caret = 2;

var sel = ifr.contentDocument.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

var el = ibody;
range.setStart(el, caret);
range.setEnd(el, caret);

sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

Look at the last two lines

Comment: In my case worked with caret = 1 it depends on child nodes existent in the body